# Binomial Distribution Problem

Tags: probability-distributions

Hello can someone please help me to answer this question it, it a binomial distribution question:

> An email message advertises the chance to win a prize if the reader follows a link to an online survey. The probability that a recipient of the email clicks on the link to the survey is 0.0016.
>   How many emails, to the nearest hundred, need to be sent out in order to have a 99% probability that at least 1000 will be answered?

Comment: Is it a homework question? What did you try?

Comment: I know that the formula for binomial distribution is  Pr(X = k) = {n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} and in this case n has to be found and p=0.0016 and the condition is that pr(X is alteast 1000)=0.99

Comment: Suppose $X$ follows a $\mathrm{Binomial}(n,p)$ distribution. What is the probability (as a function of $n$) that $X \geq 1000$? And how can you use that to answer the question?

Comment: Dont you have to know like the prob when X=0 and then u can use the formula to work it out?

Comment: If you know that $\mathbb{P}\{X \geq 1000\} = f(n)$ for some explicit expression $f(n)$, you then only have to find the smallest $n$ (rounded to hundreds) such that $f(n) \geq 0.99$.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can solve for $''n''$ analytically.  Do they want you to use some sort of approximation like the Poisson distribution?

Answer (score 2):

I think that this may be a geometric distribution question. We can use a geometric distribution to find the number of trials (emails) before we get a success (someone follows the link). We can also find the number of trials needed to be 99% certain of getting 1 success. Then we multiply that by 1000.
We have:
X~Geo(0.0016)
The number of trials needed to be 99% certain of one success is worked out as shown:

r= number of trials needed
$$P(X\le{r})\ge{0.99}$$

Therefore:
$$1-P(X\gt{r})\ge{0.99}$$

For a geometric distribution, $$P(X\gt{r})$$ is given by $$q^r$$ where q is (1-p)

Therefore:
$$1-q^r\ge{0.99}$$

$$q^r\le{0.01}$$

$$(1-0.0016)^r\le{0.01}$$

$$0.9984^r\le{0.01}$$

These logs are to base 10:

$$r\log0.9984\le{\log0.01}$$

$$r\log0.9984\le{\log0.01}$$

$$r\ge{\frac{\log0.01}{log0.9984}}$$

$$r\ge{2875.928167}$$

As r must be an integer, $$r=2876$$
This finds r for 1 email being clicked on.
Final answer=$$2876\times 1000$$
Final answer=2,876,000

That's quite a few e-mails.

Hope I helped!